# Apollo boost default state

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to create default state. And have the following setup:

```
export const GET_MOVIE = gql`
  query movie($id: String!){
    movie(id: $id){
      id
      title
      overview
      backdrop_path
      runtime
      vote_count
      vote_average
    }
  }
`;
```

here is where I'm making a request

```
export const FeaturedMovie = compose(
  graphql(GET_MOVIE, {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ data }),
    options: ownProps => ({
      variables: {
        id: `${ownProps.movie.id}`
      },
    })
  })
)(FeaturedMovieView);`

const defaults = {
  Movie: {
    __typename: 'Movie',
    Movie: 299536,
    backdrop_path: '/bOGkgRGdhrBYJSLpXaxhXVstddV.jpg',
    id: '299536',
    overview: '',
    runtime: '149',
    title: '',
    vote_average: 8.3,
    vote_count: 7600
  }
};

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.BASE_URL,
  clientState: {
    defaults
  }
});
```

There is no problem with regular queries. But default state does not work.

Comment: where do you have your query resolver defined?

Comment: Here is the thing I don't have resolvers. I reckon I should have them.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RvRcnD8wHY in this video everything works without resolvers though.

Comment: since you're passing the id in your query, you will need to define a resolver for it, also want to specify the @client

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example?